# How do I make a Google Sheets custom formula that gives the current cell the color of the input cell?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a formula that gives the current cell the color of the input cell.

Here's what I've tried:

```
function getCellColor(input) {
return input.getBackground();
}
```

I understand that returning this would not work, and even if it did it would just return the actual value and not do a setBackground method but I'm just really lost on this and don't know how to proceed.

The input is being parsed as a value and not as a "cell" object but I have no idea what the proper way to do this would be.

Comment: You cannot use `set*` methods in a custom formula.

Comment: In that case, is it actually impossible to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: With a custom formula, almost impossible. But, you can write a function in custom menu or a `onEdit` trigger. Read [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced). You can surely get the value in the custom formula, but not set it: `function getCellColor(){return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getBackground()}` should work

Comment: Hey TheMaster, thanks for a lot for the help! I'll work with this and see what I can do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user stated custom functions have limitations which includes set methods in spreadsheet [1]. You can easily create a menu that will run a specific function in which you can use all the Apps Script methods.

Here is a piece of code that will create a menu [3], and when clicked, colorCell() function will get the background color from B5 cell and set it to the active cell:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Actions')
  .addItem('Go to Cell', 'colorCell')
  .addToUi();  
}

function colorCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var color = sheet.getRange("B5").getBackgroundColor();

  //Sets color to the cell
  cell.setBackground(color);
}
```

I leave you the SpreadsheetApp documentation [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: I appreciate that you took the time to write out an alternative solution for me, I'll use what you gave me to learn more and do a workaround instead.